# Send application to back & bring to front

Tags: android, service, android-activity, background-service

I want to develop an application where it will start on particular time & close on particular time. Similar like Alarm but not alarm application.
          As per my thinking I will start an service when application first started service will check current time & particular timing to match the condition & when condition is to close application it will simply send application to background so that service will be running & when condition for wake up occurs service will bring application front.
          Is this possible? If yes please give an example links or anything helpful.
          Also I am trying to understand the service but it's little bit complex for me so if you have link which will help me to understand the service it will be very helpful.                                                                                                                                                                                      Thank You.

Problem Solved:

/**To close the activity*/

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivity(intent);
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

OR Just finish activity;

```
MainActivity.this.finish();
```

/** To start the activity*/

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
i.setComponent(cn);
startActivity(i);
```

It worked for me still I if any one have better solution please post below.

Thank You

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply close your app and keep the service running (you can do this if you don't bind the `Activity` to the `Service`)?

Comment: the specifications are like this so I can't touch the screen something is going on in activity & when specific time come it will stop the application so without touching the device & also it must get start on specific time without touching the device....

Comment: you can use alarm manager class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for time changes, and at your specified times, create an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to launch or to close your main [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: @Phill-- Thank You for Suggesting [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)