# Reorder Android task to front

Tags: android, android-intent, background-foreground

I have a problem :

My application has several activities ( *e.g. StartActivity, MainActivity* ), and a service ( *e.g. MainService* ).

When the user tap the Home button, the activity becomes no longer visible, but the service is still running ( normal workflow ).

What I have to do now is that when my service receives a particular Broadcast, I want bring to foreground the MainActivity - the existing instance - ( it is not the activity that has the intent-filter `android.intent.action.MAIN` ).

I tried [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928368/send-application-to-back-bring-to-front), but it only works with the flag : `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, and I can't use this flag because I don't want to start a new task, I just want to bring the existing to front ( and consequently avoid multiple instances of the app ).

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Comment: what probelm do you get with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK...?

Comment: I can't use this flag because I don't want to start a new task, I just want to bring the existing to front ( and consequently avoid multiple instances of the app ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` if you are starting the activity from the service.

To multiple instance you can add this to your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
android:launchMode = "SingleTask"
```

Comment: so it is impossible to launch an existing task instead of starting a new ?

Comment: add this flag to your intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY

Comment: adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` works, thanks !